# CSS3 Horizontal Dropdown Menu and Microsoft Silverlight Compatibility ... Mouseover / Hover Issues

Tags: silverlight, css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-9, mouseover

I’m trying to deploy a CSS3-based horizontal navigation menu on a still-under-construction site I’m working on.

Hover or mouseover one of the menu’s titles and a drop-down menu appears.  Move the mouse off of the title, or off of the list of dropdown items, and the menu collapses.  So, the dropdown list of items stays open as long as it can ‘see’ the mouse pointer.

The menu features containers that allow for the presentation of content from the site, or even other sites. E.g., it can display images or entire webpages.  I’m attempting to display an object created with Microsoft’s Silverlight platform. The object is embedded on another page of my site and, via php include, it plays well with the menu in all browsers I’ve tested it on … except Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.  (Haven't tried IE10 yet.)

In the IE9 case, the Silverlight object appears as expected, but the dropdown menu collapses as soon as the mouse touches the displayed Silverlight object.  I.e., the CSS3 menu loses sight of the mouse and the dropdown collapses the moment the mouse pointer touches the Silverlight object.

I haven't been able to find much in the way of help for this one.

Any thoughts or guidance are much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: So, I've narrowed this one down.  As it turns out the menu system I'm working with doesn't seem to handle iframes in the IE9 environment.  Please disregard.

Comment: This issue remains unresolved. However, it is being narrowed down, and may in fact not  be related to the menu script.  Please disregard.